# Auto complete not working it is throwing an error iElement.autocomplete is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am  trying  to  build  an  auto complete on search text box  using Angularjs. but  getting  an  error  iElement.autocomplete is not a function.

code

```
  <body ng-controller='FriendController'>
  <form ng-submit="addFriend()">
 <input type="email" auto-complete ui-items="fbFriends" ng-model="friend" autofocus />
</form>

<ul ng-repeat="friend in friends">
  <li>
    {{friend.text}}
  </li>
</ul>

<script>
   var addFriendAppModule = angular.module('addFriendApp', []);
   addFriendAppModule.controller('FriendController',
    function($scope) {

      var friendArr = [];
    $scope.fbFriends = [
         {
          value: "manu", 
          email: "sept@gmail.com"
        },
        {
        value: "manu123", 
        email: "sept123@gmail.com"
        }
    ];
    $scope.friends = friendArr;         
    $scope.friend = '';

    $scope.addFriend = function() {
        var newFriend = $scope.friend.trim();
        if (newFriend.length === 0) {
            return;
        }
        friendArr.push(
            {text: newFriend}
        );
    };      
});

addFriendAppModule.directive('autoComplete', function($timeout) {
    return function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
        iElement.autocomplete({
            source: scope[iAttrs.uiItems],
            focus: function(event,ui) {
                iElement.val(ui.item.email);
                return false;
            },
            select: function(event, ui) {
                    iElement.val(ui.item.email);
                    return false;
                  //  iElement.trigger('input');
                   // iElement.trigger('submit');
            }
        }).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
            return $("<li></li>")
                .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                .append(item.email)
                .appendTo(ul);
        };
    }
});
```

Can  anyone tell me what i miss? I have also tried   datalist  html5 tag  for  autocomplete  but  it did not work on IE8. so  i  drop this approach.If anyone has  better approach for  auto complete please  share.

Answer (score 2):

It won't work as IE8 doesn't has support for HTML5 and also in the current version of angularjs they have dropped the support for IE8. [Check here.](http://blog.angularjs.org/2013/12/angularjs-13-new-release-approaches.html)

Comment: @jayaram..do you have any  better approach for auto complete which is cross browser compatible?